# How do I add description and keyword to the front page?

Tags: panels, meta-tags

I would like to know how to set description and meta keywords for the front page. I use the [Meta tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module for articles, but it is not working for the front page.

I use Panel as my front page.

My website is http://www.techiestuffs.com, and runs on Drupal 7.

if you see the HTML source of the front page, it only contains the following HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.techiestuffs.com/sites/default/files/favicon.png" type="image/png"/>
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)"/>
<title>TechieStuffs | Stuffs for Geeks</title>
```

I had tried adding these functions in template.php:

```
function yourtheme_page_alter($page) {
  $meta_description = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
    'name' => 'description',
    'content' =>  'Description about the site'
  ));

  $meta_keywords = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
    'name' => 'keywords',
    'content' =>  'Some Keywords about the site'
  ));

  drupal_add_html_head($meta_description, 'meta_description');
  drupal_add_html_head($meta_keywords, 'meta_keywords');
}
```

But this function does not seems to work as you can see in my websites source code.

Does anyone know how to work out this?

Comment: I checked meta tag module, you can set default for front page...

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answer, if the answer is helpful for you consider selecting it as the correct answer. There is a checkmark below the answer ratings. ▲ ▼ √

Comment: If you are using Panels for your home page and the MetaTag module https://drupal.org/project/metatag you need to make sure that in addition to enabling the basic MetaTag module, you also enable MetaTag: Panel submodule. This will allow you to set metadata for panel pages.

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 6 I used [Nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) which allowed you to set meta tags on the front page as a configuration. In D7 this has been replaced by [Meta Tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) which may do the same thing or you.

Comment: But My front page is a panel so the front page ovberride doesn't work and i also tried to assign meta tags for panels but it is also not showing up.

Comment: Does it work for a simple front page? It being a panel shouldn't matter I would have thought.

Answer (score 0):

Add them in your theme file; whichever theme you're using, it should have an HTML skeleton that you can change.

Comment: I used this code in template.php

Comment: drupal_add_html_head( $meta_description, 'meta_description' );
drupal_add_html_head( $meta_keywords, 'meta_keywords' );

Comment: but still meta not showing up

Comment: add it statically in .tpl file of theme where you have head tag. check you theme folder and front.tpl file.

Comment: is your meta description is dynamic ?

Comment: No static for front page

Comment: then don't use 

drupal_add_html_head( $meta_description, 'meta_description' ); drupal_add_html_head( $meta_keywords, 'meta_keywords' );

above code :

just go to front page.tpl check it in your theme and add there meta description.

Comment: I could not find frontpage.tpl instead i have page.tpl in my theme folder ( i use bartik theme )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2071/discussion-between-vividvilla-and-gaurav)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Views or Panels do not have meta tags by default. If you use either one for your frontpage, you can use the [Meta Tags Quick Module](http://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick), which allows the addition of the main meta tags for any path that is generated by Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Path-Based Metatags option in [Meta tags quick module](http://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick), enable module and go to front page, you will see Path-Based Metatags option...when you click on the option, you can fill in the fields that you want, you can also set the fields that you want to display (admin/config/search/metatags_quick)...

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old thread, but in case people find and still looking for an easy solution. I didn't like the Drupal way or Meta Quick. Found this super easy module, Simple Meta, adds a tab at left side directly on every page. I edit only description and meta tag instantly appeared. https://drupal.org/project/simplemeta.